# Yii2: how to disable yiiActiveForm() function append to <body>?

Tags: javascript, yii, yii2

In yii2 I have simple `ActiveForm`:

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['enableClientValidation' => false]) ?>
<?= $form->field($model, ...
```

This adds before `</body>` tag javascript code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">jQuery(document).ready(function () {
jQuery('#w0').yiiActiveForm([], []);
});</script>
```

I want to disable this code and add it manually in my custom js file. So, how to disable? The main goal is to put everything (including jQuery) to one big js file and run it on every page with `async` attribute to speed up performance.

p.s. I must remove this js code generated by Yii, because if I use `async`, where jQuery also located, there is an error: jQuery() is not defined

Comment: a simple suggestion dont try to do it, you get messed.

Answer (score 1):

If you change your code to

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['enableClientScript' => false]) ?>
```

The form will not output any JavaScript, check out the [documentation for ActiveForm](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-widgets-activeform#$enableClientScript-detail), there it says:

> **$enableClientScript** *public property*
>
> Whether to hook up `yii.activeForm` JavaScript plugin. This property must be set `true` if you want to support client validation and/or AJAX validation, or if you want to take advantage of the `yii.activeForm plugin`. When this is `false`, the form will not generate any JavaScript.

The problem I see is that you will need to add manually all the code normally generated by the widget, validation, error messages, all of it.

I have never used this besides trying it, briefly, to see that it stops the tag from being generated.

A better option may be to create your own component `MyActiveForm` and override `registerClientScript()` to add the `async` attribute. Maybe you could even provide a `enableAsyncClientScriptLoading` attribute that allowed setting this through the configuration array.